# MySQL Advanced select query checking data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Database that I'm struggling to do a query for. The main table is `people` and what I am trying to do is `add` onto the end of the select query the `id` from the `favourites` table ONLY if the `client_member_id` matches.

The idea is to loop through each `People` row and at the end of the row add on the `f.id` if that persons id is in the `favourites` table AND it matches the `id` of the `client_member_id`.

The `client_member_id` is an id given to each client so that when they Favourite a person then the details get put to the favourites table. This would be either `1` or `2`. In the SQLFiddle example the expected output of the `FAVE_ID` when `client_member_id` is `2` would be `68` `69` but if `client_member_id` is `1` then `FAVE_ID` would both be `null`

I have gotten it to a point where it seems to duplicate the rows and I need it to be distinct.

```
SELECT *, j.company_id as companyid, j.id as jid, p.id as pid,
    (CASE WHEN f.client_member_id = 2 AND p.id = f.people_id THEN f.id ELSE null END) AS fave_id,
    (CASE WHEN f.client_member_id = 2 AND p.id = f.people_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fave
FROM people p
INNER JOIN favourites f
INNER JOIN job j 
ON p.job_id = j.id
WHERE p.company_id = 1
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d62b5d/1)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the DISTINCT operator.

Comment: I see no duplicate rows in your results, please be more clear in your explanation or provide a sample output.

Comment: @Arth when I run `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d62b5d/1` I see that the people are duplicated twice. 2 instances of each person one with a `fave_id` and one that has `null`

Comment: Of course they are, you have joined each person to both favourite rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN to favourites to get rid of the ungainly CASE:

```
    SELECT *,
           j.company_id companyid,
           j.id jid,
           p.id pid,
           f.id fave_id,
           f.id IS NOT NULL fave
      FROM people p    
INNER JOIN job j 
        ON p.job_id = j.id
 LEFT JOIN favourites f
        ON f.people_id=p.id
       AND f.client_member_id=2
     WHERE p.company_id = 1
  ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

**N.B** This will return only two rows for your fiddle with `fave_id` and `fave`, NOT NULL and 1, but in the event that you have a person without a corresponding favourite then you get `fave_id` and `fave`, NULL and 0.

Answer (score 1):

There are no duplicates, you have 4 rows because of fave_id and fave columns. If you want to filter them then here is an example how to show only values for fave=1 :

```
SELECT *, j.company_id as companyid, j.id as jid, p.id as pid,
    (CASE WHEN f.client_member_id = 2 AND p.id = f.people_id THEN f.id ELSE null END) AS fave_id,
    (CASE WHEN f.client_member_id = 2 AND p.id = f.people_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fave
FROM people p
INNER JOIN favourites f
INNER JOIN job j 
ON p.job_id = j.id
WHERE p.company_id = 1 AND f.client_member_id = 2 AND p.id = f.people_id
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Comment: This is a mangled use of INNER JOIN, and your CASE is completely negated by your WHERE condition.

Comment: This is not MY case. It's from the question.

Comment: I know that, but why include redundant code in a weird kind of half solution. Also sort your `INNER JOIN` to favourites out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d62b5d/12)

```
SELECT *, j.company_id as companyid, j.id as jid, p.id as pid,
    (CASE WHEN f.client_member_id = 2 THEN f.id ELSE null END) AS fave_id,
    (CASE WHEN f.client_member_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fave
FROM people p
INNER JOIN job j ON p.job_id = j.id
left JOIN favourites f on f.people_id = p.id
WHERE p.company_id = 1
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

You didn't bind your favourites table join to anything and therefore you had number of people rows * number of favourites returned. I've used a left join as I'm guessing that you can't guarantee that there will be a favourite for every person in the people table? Else if you can then just change to inner join.

Regards

Liam